# How to solve for $x$ in exact terms where $2x^2\sin(x^2) = 3\cos(x^2)$

Tags: calculus

I want to know if it is possible to solve for $x$ without approximating. The equation is:

$$2x^2\sin(x^2) = 3\cos(x^2)$$

There are multiple solutions, but the answer I am looking for is about $0.9441$. Does anyone know if this is even possible? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: No, this will not be possible.

Comment: I doubt it but it's equivalent with $\cot(x^2)=\frac23 x^2$ so if you can find the solutions to $\cot(x) = \frac23 x$ but I doubt you can find it.

Comment: You can rewrite this as $$x^2\tan(x^2) = \dfrac{3}{2}$$ and then replace $x^2$ with another variable $u$ for $u\tan(u) = \dfrac{3}{2}$ You can define a function $$f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \left[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ such that $$f(x)\tan(f(x)) = x$$ which implies on the image of $f$, this is the inverse function to $u\tan u$. Then, you are looking for $f\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$. Such a function would be similar to the Lambert-W function. Once you have a solution, take the square root and you found a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a closed form solution.

The best we can do is to show that a solution exists and determine it by numerical methods.

For the first part let consider $y=x^2\ge0$ then

$$2y\sin y = 3\cos y \iff f(y)=\frac23y\tan y=1$$

from wich we can see that form IVT exactly one solution exists in the interval $y\in\left(0,\frac \pi 2\right)$ and exactly one solution for any other interval $y\in\left(\frac \pi 2+k\pi,\frac 32\pi +k\pi\right)$ with integer $k\ge 1$.

Note also that for $y$ large

$$\frac23y\tan y=1 \iff \frac23\tan y=\frac1y \to 0 $$

therefore solutions for $y$ approximate the values $\frac \pi 2 +k\pi$ for $k$ large.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: This might be viewed as the numerical technique in addition to user's theoretical justification)

There is no algebraic solution to this equation.
That is because you can not isolate $x$.

However you can numerically approximate a solution.
For example with Newton's method.

For that observe:

$f(x)=2x^2\sin(x^2)-3\cos(x^2)$

Now calculate $f'(x)$ and guess a start value for your approximation. Since you know the value already, you might take $x_0=1$.

Then iterate the formula:

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

So with $x_0=1$ you have $x_1=1-\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}$ and do that over and over again until you reach a satisfying approximation.

Comment: So what is x sub 0 and how is it 1? Like, f(0) is -3, right?

Comment: @Octavius $x_0$ is a guessed starting point for the iteration. Since you know that the solution is $\approx 0.9$ it is good to take a value close to that. You could have taken an other value. It does not really matter. It could be when there are more solutions to the equation, that you do not iterate one of them. A way to find such $x_0$ could be to check values for your function $f$. $f(0)=-3$. For $f(1)$ I need a calculater, but there should be a change of sign, so f(0)<0 and f(1)>0 so there is a root $x_0\in[0,1]$. So we just pick $x_0=1$ and start the iteration from there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Answer (score 0):

As said, no analytical solution and numerical methods should be used.

However, you could have a good approximation of the first zero of function
$$f(y)=2y\sin (y)- 3\cos (y)$$ building its simplest Padé approximant "close" to the root $y=a$. This would write
$$f(y)\sim \frac{f(a)+ \left(f'(a)-\frac{f(a) f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}\right) (y-a)}   {1-\frac{ f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(y-a) }$$ and setting the numerator equal to zero would then give
$$y=a+\frac{2 f(a) f'(a)}{f(a) f''(a)-2 f'(a)^2}$$

Using $a=\frac \pi 3$ would give
$$y=\frac \pi 3+\frac{270 \sqrt{3}-8 \pi  \left(18+\sqrt{3} \pi \right)}{1539+20 \pi  \left(3 \sqrt{3}+\pi \right)}\approx 0.988303$$ while the exact solution would be $\approx 0.988241$.